# Temporal vs Time series database

Tags: database, time-series, temporal-database

I am a newbie to Database Systems and I was wondering what is difference between Temporal database and Time-series database. I have searched on the internet but I am not getting any comparison of the two.

Answer (score 5):

**Time-series database**: A time series database is a database that is optimized to store time-series data. This is data that is stored along with a time stamp so that changes in the data can be measured over time. [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) is a time-series database used by Sound Cloud, Docker and Show Max.

Real world uses:

- Autonomous trading algorithms, continuously collects data on market changes.
- DevOps monitoring stores data of the state of the system over its run time.

**Temporal databases** contain data that is time sensitive. That is, the data are stored with time indicators such as the valid time (time for which the entry remains valid) and transaction time (time the data was entered into the database). Any database can be used as a temporal database if the data is managed correctly.

Real world uses:

- Shop inventory systems keep track of stock quantities, time of purchase and best-before-dates.
- Industrial processes that are dependant on valid time data during manufacturing and sales.

Answer (score 4):

A temporal database stores events which happen at a certain time or for a certain period. For example, the address of a customer may change so when you join the invoice table with the customer the answer will be different before and after the move of the customer.

A time-series database stores time-series which are array of number indexed by time. Like the evolution of the temperature with one measure every hour. Or the stock value every second.